# Hebrew character looks like a division sign when using iconv with FPDF

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, fpdf

When I use `iconv` to convert encoding from `UTF-8` to `windows-1255`, all the Hebrew letters show up correctly, except for `ק`, which shows up as the division symbol: `÷`:

```
$pdf->AddFont('Arial', '', 'arial.php');
$pdf->setFont('Arial', '', 15);
$value = iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1255', 'ק');
$pdf->Write(1, $value);
```

I use a PHP package to create PDF files. So it shows up as `÷` in the PDF file, but when I copy that sign from the PDF file to Google search for example, it shows up as `ק` again.

How can I fix that and show it as `ק` in the PDF file as well?

I even followed the tutorial on how to create fonts with the correct encoding on the fdpf website (To create the `font.z` and `font.php` files)

Update: I noticed that for the mapping file for the cp1255, The line that maps to the Hebrew letter `ק` is the same line that has the extended ASCII code for the division sign:

from `cp1255.map`:

```
!F7 U+05E7 afii57687
```

also, here is an image of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced your error and i got the same error and the reason is use of incorrect font family and encoding. Please find the solution of the issue below

---

### **UPDATED NOTE:**

On further discussion and debugging it was discovered  that the MakeFont script in the old version i.e. version prior to FPDF 1.85 is buggy and throws errors, yet the files are created so it's hard to notice.

Hence If anyone is using FPDF for hebrew before version 1.85 either update you MakeFont script or use version FPDF 1.85 or later for generating .php and .z files for fonts.

---

***step - 1***  using makefont function in pdf create the font file using "font-family.ttf" of your choice. It will create 2 files font-family-name.php and font-family-name.z  .... Place both the files in fonts folder in fpdf directory.

Please note you have to use encoding cp1255 for hebrew.

`MakeFont('Noto_Sans_Hebrew/noto-sans-hebrew.ttf','cp1255',);`

Alternatively you can create it online as well here -> [makefont - fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/)

***step -2*** to use it you will need to addfont and setfont for the document. Please have a look at the code below.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

//for hebrew encoding is cp12555. 
$str = 'ק מה שלומך';
$string =iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1255', $str); 
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddFont('noto-sans-hebrew','','noto-sans-hebrew.php');
$pdf->SetFont('noto-sans-hebrew','',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$string);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

GENERATED PDF IMAGE :

[image]

---

**Useful links:**

- [Adding new fonts and encodings](http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto7.htm)
- [Font File Generation](http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/)
- [MARC 21 Specifications for Record Structure, Character Sets, and Exchange Media
  Code Table Basic Hebrew](https://www.loc.gov/marc/specifications/codetables/BasicHebrew.html)

---

I do not understand hebrew. But please do let me know in  for issues in comment.

Comment: The photo your posted seem correct. But for me, it still shows `÷` instead of `ק` even though I copied your code. I got an older version of FPDF and when I create the font using the command line (Not the script method): `php makefont\makefont.php C:\Windows\Fonts\Rubik-Light.ttf cp1255`, it works with warnings though (some warning about `count()` method). Could it be that the old version and/or the command line method have bugs in it? Btw, did you also have the error where it showed you `÷` instead of `ק`? I also added a photo of what I see.

Comment: yes i got the same ÷ symbol.. you need to change arial font ... it does not support it fully ... i have used noto hebrew font from google font...

Comment: I also tried with `Rubik-Style` from Google Fonts which was found after I added "Hebrew" to the filter. Could that also not be fully supported? Update: I just tried with `noto-sans-hebrew` as well, same issue. Could it be some bug in the old version I am using (1.81), or a bug in the command line way of generating the `.php` and `.z` files?

Comment: i used 1.85 for this... but i dont think it older version should be an issue... request you to download the fonts then use online link provided in answer to make php and .z file.. and place it in fonts folder fpdf ...

Comment: please note there are two variables 1. correct encoding. 2. support for that encoding in font...

Comment: Anant, I just copied the latest `makefont` folder content and it worked! Looks like the older makefont is bugged for Hebrew at least. But now I have another issue, since it writes Hebrew in reverse, I have to use `strrev($str)`, but as soon as I use it on the original `$str`, it gives me `detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string` - do you also get it if you use `strrev`?

Comment: hi, this is bit strange as on my system i did not required to do ```strrev``` ..... my input was same as output( in picture) .... funny thing is when i was pasting the same code on Stack overflow the input string is reversed (as you can see in code).... see again when i am posting it in comment its generating it in reverse order ->  ```ק מה שלומך ```

Comment: Haha yes it reverses the Hebrew in the output. What you see in the code and here in the comment if the way it's supposed to be, that's why I needed to use the reverse function.

Comment: ok... got it ...Thank you for clarity .. .. lack of knowledge on my part though :P  :)

Comment: Haha thank you for the help . If you add my answer content to your answer, like saying that I should also check new version then I can mark your answer instead of mine, because my issue was the version (I already did what you did before, but your answer helped me with debugging), if you look down you see I answered to myself that's what I mean by "my answer"

Comment: I have updated the answer to include your's as well. It should help others as well.... :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used the correct fonts that are supported (Hebrew fonts), yet I had the error.

Then I found out that the MakeFont script in the old version I had is buggy and throws errors, yet the files are created so it's hard to notice.

So when I used the most updated MakeFont script, it fixed it